# Using format does not give me expected answer

Tags: javascript, date-fns

```
tests.map((test) => {
      format(test.Hour, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH`)
      console.log(format(test.Hour, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH`));
    })
    console.log(tests);
```

I am trying to convert some data i pulled from an API to a better date format for my purpose by using date-fns' format function. When i loop over it, the format function inside the console.log displays 2022-11-23 H:23, but when i console log it after the map has run, it shows me the value i dont want: 2022-11-23T23:00:00.000Z

Any help is appriciated, thanks !

Comment: You have a mistake in your map statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return values from your `map` and save a new array out of it with formatted values. Or you can use `forEach` instead of `map` to directly alter the existing array.

```js
const newTests = tests.map((test) => {
  return format(test.Hour, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH`);
})
console.log(newTests);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the offical page of map function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
const numbers = [1, 4, 9];
const roots = numbers.map((num) => Math.sqrt(num));
// roots is now     [1, 2, 3]
// numbers is still [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Always format code as code to make it easier to read

Comment: I edited as you suggest. Thanks for feedback. @moken